# Postfix block local user from sending

Tags: postfix

In Postfix, how to disallow a local user to send emails, say joe@mail.example.com, to anywhere?

I wrote a `sender_access` file with the following lines

```
# cat sender_access
joe REJECT
joe@mail.example.com REJECT
```

And loaded as a hash `postmap hash:sender_access`, then I added in `main.cf` the row

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
```

and finally I restarted postfix. But the user still writes into the active queue. Maybe there is some other option interference in the conf.

This is my `postconf -n`:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
allow_percent_hack = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = mail.example.com, localhost.neencloud.it, , localhost, mail.example.com
myhostname = mail.example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

This is part of `mail.log`:

```
Aug 12 15:59:09 ne538 postfix/qmgr[31440]: 4601E7AD8EE7: from=<joe@mail.example.com>, size=115624, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 12 15:59:09 ne538 postfix/pickup[16329]: 70E627AD8EE8: uid=1051 from=<joe>
Aug 12 15:59:09 ne538 postfix/cleanup[16320]: 70E627AD8EE8: message-id=<20130812135909.70E627AD8EE8@mail.example.com>
Aug 12 15:59:09 ne538 postfix/error[16339]: 4601E7AD8EE7: to=<mailaddress@yahoo.com>, relay=none, delay=0.45, delays=0.32/0/0/0.13, dsn=4.7.0, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: host mta5.am0.yahoodns.net[63.250.192.45] refused to talk to me: 421 4.7.0 [TS01] Messages from 85.159.145.207 temporarily deferred due to user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see http://postmaster.yahoo.com/421-ts01.html)
Aug 12 15:59:09 ne538 postfix/qmgr[31440]: 70E627AD8EE8: from=<joe@mail.example.com>, size=115630, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 12 15:59:09 ne538 postfix/pickup[16329]: 91B8A7AD8EE9: uid=1051 from=<joe>
Aug 12 15:59:09 ne538 postfix/cleanup[16210]: 91B8A7AD8EE9: message-id=<20130812135909.91B8A7AD8EE9@mail.example.com>
Aug 12 15:59:09 ne538 postfix/smtp[7647]: 73BCC7AD8EE0: host mta6.am0.yahoodns.net[98.138.112.35] refused to talk to me: 421 4.7.0 [TS01] Messages from 85.159.145.207 temporarily deferred due to user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see http://postmaster.yahoo.com/421-ts01.html
Aug 12 15:59:09 ne538 postfix/error[16335]: 70E627AD8EE8: to=<anothermailaddress@yahoo.com>, relay=none, delay=0.52, delays=0.3/0/0/0.22, dsn=4.7.0, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: host mta5.am0.yahoodns.net[63.250.192.45] refused to talk to me: 421 4.7.0 [TS01] Messages from 85.159.145.207 temporarily deferred due to user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see http://postmaster.yahoo.com/421-ts01.html)
Aug 12 15:59:09 ne538 postfix/qmgr[31440]: 91B8A7AD8EE9: from=<joe@mail.example.com>, size=115625, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 12 15:59:09 ne538 postfix/pickup[16329]: C6C807AD8EEA: uid=1051 from=<joe>
Aug 12 15:59:09 ne538 postfix/cleanup[16320]: C6C807AD8EEA: message-id=<20130812135909.C6C807AD8EEA@mail.example.com>
Aug 12 15:59:09 ne538 postfix/smtp[7647]: 73BCC7AD8EE0: host mta5.am0.yahoodns.net[66.196.118.37] refused to talk to me: 421 4.7.0 [TS01] Messages from 85.159.145.207 temporarily deferred due to user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see http://postmaster.yahoo.com/421-ts01.html
```

Comment: where is mail log with successful delivering? output of the postconf -n would be more preferred

Comment: Mail From: Headers are trivially spoofable, and using them as a method of control is asking for problems.. if you do SASL logins, a program like policyd will give you much better control.

Comment: Yes nice point but joe is a local user. Do I need to configure SPF on this server even to stop him?

Comment: local users mean smtp restrictions, not smtpd.

Comment: Mmh so where should I work on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are looking to allow certain users access to local mail submission, the parameter you need to use is [authorized_submit_users](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#authorized_submit_users), the only issue is that it is a whitelist, hopefully you don't have lots of local users who need to send email. If you have postfix 2.4+ you can use a format like this: `authorized_submit_users = !joe, static:all`
which is joe no, everyone else yes.

Comment: Glad to have been of assistance :)

Comment: As for completeness, I allowed the other users to send by writing the following directive:

``authorized_submit_users = !joe, static:anyone``

Answer (score 0):

I believe this article will give you the required information:
http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html